# Is it possible to have Spring Boot on Gluon Mobile?

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

Is it possible to have Spring Boot and a REST API from Spring, included inside Gluon Mobile?

With JavaFX, it's possible. But what about Gluon Mobile JavaFX?
https://better-coding.com/javafx-spring-boot-gradle-project-setup-guide-and-test/

Comment: Why do you want to do that? REST API is the server part and Gluon the client.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Yes I know. I just have an idea of making a GUI server app. With GluonHQ Mobile, I can also do desktop :)